# Format ext3 disk space from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ext3, formatting

Is it possible to format an ext3 disk space (on an extended partition) from Windows 7? Any utility available to do that?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to suggest a ubuntu boot or maybe a [GParted](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=9951) based [solution](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/).
Turns out, this is [already discussed at Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/45985/repairing-ext3-partitions-using-windows) (where it is probably more suited).